# how to detect RDP on uncommon ports with nmap?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, nmap

I want to scan an IP range and check if any IPs in that scope have RDP enabled on other ports than `3389`. 
I've tried this to confirm that the server has RDP:

```
nmap --script rdp-enum-encryption -p 33999 -n -Pn -sS -T4 1.2.3.4
```

And tried this but takes so long (about 40 Seconds) to check only 1 IP:

```
nmap -sV --script unusual-port --script rdp-enum-encryption -p 33999 -n -Pn -sS -T4 1.2.3.4
```

What I want to do is to scan an IP range for RDP and confirm they have RDP enabled. Because sometimes default RDP is enabled on a server but the server itself is Linux or that 3389 port do something else. So in summary, Scan an IP range with a range of ports like 3380-3389 and check if they are really RDP or no.

#### EDIT:

Also tried this but it taking so long to scan ports. All I want is to check if `Service Version` is RDP or no.

```
nmap -T5 -p T:33999 -sV --version-intensity 1 -iL ips.txt -oG rdp.txt --min-rate=50000 -sS -n -Pn --open -vv
```